# wp_hash_password unexpected behaviour

Tags: password

When I run `wp_hash_password("password")` twice the outputs are different. I was under the impression that this is not how hashes are supposed to work. So how should I use `wp_hash_password` to compare two hashes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's just not the way it works. `wp_hash_password()` will always return a different value for the same password due to [SALTing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Salt_%28cryptography%29).

You are searching for the [wp_check_password()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_check_password) function.

Comment: Of course, stupid of me, thannks

Answer (score 0):

You can use **wp_check_password()** , see http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_check_password

```
global $current_user;
get_currentuserinfo();
$user = $current_user;
    if ( wp_check_password( $_POST['current_password'], $user->user_pass, $user->ID) )//check password
   {
             //go ahead and change the password of stuff
             //....
   }
```

Comment: Please add a short explanation to your answer.