# wp_hash_password create a different hash everytime

Tags: password, encryption

I've already seen this topic: [wp_hash_password unexpected behaviour](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/117531/wp-hash-password-unexpected-behaviour)

And the problem is similar.
I'm creating an API system where api_key and api_secret are the same as username and user_pwd. The problem is that, of course, i can't know the user password, so it will be the same encrypted password from the DB.

The user will put his password, so i need to encrypt it in the same way as wordpress and compare it to the password/key in the DB.

But from what i've seen, everytime i use wp_hash_password(password) i get a different hash. So how wordpress can compare the hash with the one in the DB? How can i get the same hash to compare it?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: That is the same problem as the topic you've linked: you either can't use wp_hash_password, or you'd have to modify it to use a fixed random initialisation vector (which weakens security slightly).

Comment: Can you do something else e.g. give the user a generated password to use as their API secret rather than actually using the password? WordPress's authentication code is easy to extend if you're worried about having to do the validation afterwards.

Comment: The answer is in the topic you've linked: to check the password you should use [wp_check_password](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_check_password)